# How a function-scoped static variable may lead to incompatibility with future uses of the function's code located in shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-variables

Rule 3.3.1 of the [HIC++ Coding](http://www.bwz.se/nohau/UserFiles/Files/1115_PRQA%20Higt%20Integrity%20C%20ver%204.pdf) Standard restricts using variables with static storage duration even if they are declared in a block scope:

> The order of initialization of block scope objects with static storage duration is well defined.  However, the lifetime of such an object ends at program termination, which may be incompatible with future uses of the code, e.g. as a shared library.

```cpp
Application const & theApp()  
{  
  static  Application  app; // Non-Compliant  
  return  app;  
}
```

The question is what the incompatibilites can occur.

UPD. After I got reasonable remarks from @Employed-Russian I realized that some clarifications needed. I can imagine some issues with multi-process access to static variables. For example, on some Linux implementations the same memory shared with forked process until first memory write. It calls copy-on-write. So if we have following code executed on such system

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() {cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    ~A() {cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
};

static void f()
{
    static A a;
}

int main()
{
    f();

    fork();    

    return 0;
}
```

we could get output like

```
A
~A
~A
```

that is it, double call of destructor with single call of constructor. Which may not supposed to be because on other system we can get `A ~A A ~A`. So we can imagine some issues with static variables in common, but what is the particular problem with shared libraries and block-scoped statics?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is what the incompatibilites can occur.

As an example, the library may become unusable in a multi-threaded program in which not all threads are terminated before `exit` is called.

That is, if thread `T0` called `exit`, the `Application` destructor will be called at some point (because it was registered with `atexit` on the first call to `theApp()`).

If thread `T1` is still running, and has a reference to `theApp.app`, it will have now have a reference to destructed object, and will likely crash.

This is known as at-exit race, and may be highly irreproducible (if `T0` reaches `sys_exit` before `T1` has a chance to crash, you will observe normal exit).

**Update:**

> double call of destructor. Which isn't supposed to be

You are *mistaken*: this is working *exactly* as it should. There is no double call to destructor here: you have two processes, and each destructs its own object (as it should).

Comment: Good point but as I can see this is not an issue with shared libs only. If we define theApp directly in our application, we will get the same result, do we?

Comment: @chimpp Yes, you can shoot yourself in the foot the same way in an application. But (unlike an application developer), as a library writer you don't (usually) get to control which applications are going to use it. This applies to all libraries, I don't see what's special / why they called out *shared* library in particular.

Comment: @chimpp I've updated the answer to address your "double destructor" point as well.

Comment: `You are mistaken: this is working exactly as it should.` Thanks for the remarks. I've updated question too) The point is that we have different behaviour on different systems which may not supposed to.

Comment: @chimpp You are mistaken on that point as well: *every* UNIX system in existence will have the *same* (correct) behavior.

Comment: As for me, if I had the control flow's inconsistency across different platforms, it would be inappropriate to use such code in a cross-platform application.